# WMS MapServer OpenLayers 4 Output is blank

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver

Tested the MapServer WMS Server with GetMap and GetCapabilities, but OpenLayers shows up blank. Using QGIS as WMS client also fails saying error downloading. The OSM layer in the OpenLayers works fine when the map projection is set to EPSG:3857, and doesn't work when EPSG:4326 is used. The local WMS service doesn't get displayed in either case. The OpenLayers template works fine. (But that's not even a WMS Service that's just the browse mode)

WMS Mapfile:

```
    MAP
    NAME "distt"
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    EXTENT 68 6 98 38
    SHAPEPATH "/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/data/"
    SIZE 600 600
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    PROJECTION
         "init=epsg:4326"
    END  
    WEB
      IMAGEPATH "D:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/data"  
      IMAGEURL "D:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/data"
      METADATA
        "wms_title"           "distt"
        "wms_onlineresource"  "http://127.0.0.1/ms4w/apache/cgi-in/mapserv.exe?map=D:\ms4w\apache\htdocs\data\MAP1.map"
        "wms_srs"             "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_format" "image/png"
        "wms_enable_request" "*"
        "ows_enable_request" "*"
      END
    END

    LAYER
      NAME "distt"
      TYPE POLYGON
      STATUS ON
      DATA India_districts_shp
      METADATA
      "wms_title" "distt"
      "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326"
      "wms_server_version" "1.1.1"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
      "ows_enable_request" "*"
    END
    PROJECTION
         "init=epsg:4326"
    END  
      CLASS
      NAME "Countries"    
      STYLE
        COLOR 200 0 200
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0 
        END #STYLE
      END # CLASS
    END #LAYER

  END # MAP
```

HTML Openlayers:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
          #map {
            height: 512px;
            width: 1024px;
          }
          .ol-attribution a { color: black; }
        </style>
        <title>MNCFC CROP Map</title>
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1\build\ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Map</h1>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>  

          <script type="text/javascript">



           var layers = [
         new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),

          new ol.layer.Image({
              extent:[68,6,98,38],
              source:new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                url:'http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:\\ms4w\\apache\\htdocs\\data\\MAP1.map',
                params:{'LAYERS': 'distt'},
                ratio: 10,
                serverType: 'mapserver'
              }),
            })
          ];
          var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: layers, 
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
             projection: 'EPSG:4326',
              //center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([83, 22]),
              center: ol.proj.transform([83, 22], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
              zoom: 4.5
            })
          });
          map.addLayer(layers);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: have you checked the log files ?

Comment: msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. At least one layer name required in LAYERS. @Shiko

Comment: Try this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86964/one-of-my-wms-layer-is-not-loading-the-image-tiles

Comment: @Shiko Ive cross checked as much as I could from the mentioned url and more, but most use openlayers 2 syntax. Ive added brackets, and corrected a spelling error, but I dont see anything else.

Comment: Why STATUS is OFF?

Comment: @juminet it was one of many errors. Ive changed it now, but continue to get the same errors. Will edit code on question now.

Comment: What if you change the name of the service to something different from the layet

Comment: When you say you have tried a GetCapabilities request, what is the response, are there any reported issues.

Comment: @nmtoken Ive tried with different layer and service names. I get no errors and warnings in the .exe(/xml).

Comment: The WMS is set to respond to only EPSG:4326, so if you request in EPSG:3857 it won't work.  You can get the WMS to give you the map in EPSG:3857 by adding it to the list of supported projections with `"wms_srs"   "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"`

Comment: @nmtoken I understand(i think) why osm wont load when its set to 4326, but my shp doesnt work even when everything is set to 4326(tried removing the osm source as well)

Comment: Does the WMS service work in qgis? I'm still not sure from your question/comments whether the service is generally working, but you can't access it through openlayers, or if the problem is with the service itself

Comment: @nmtoken The getmap and getfeatures services work indicating wms to be functional. but qgis isnt able to download the wms service, and also niether is openlayers. I tried geoserver, and obviously it worked fine(i can assume shapefiles data itself is not the problem)

Comment: Not sure why you say that obviously GeoServer worked, why is it obvious?  If you can't access the service in QGIS, then the problem is probably with the service configuration, or access to the service. You can use fiddler  and QGIS in combo to see what requests are generated.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you solve this problem in meantime?

Comment: @AndreasMüller I don't remember, I've moved onto other fields. But I've thought about it and the best my memory serves me is that, it was something to do with colour of the background,outline,transparency, layer in the MAPFILE. Mess around with those because I remember feeling very stupid once I figured it out.